# asp-page with multiple asp-routes not finding page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a Razor page with the following @page and model:

```
@page "{slug1}/{slug2}/{someId:Guid?}/{step:int}"
```

--

```
public async Task<PageResult> OnGetAsync(string slug1, string slug2, Guid? someId, int step = 1)
{
    //...
}
```

On another page I link to the page in question like this (notice the missing "someId"):

```
<a asp-page="thepage" asp-route-Slug1="slug1" asp-route-Slug2="slug2" asp-route-Step="3">Open step 3</a>
```

But the link doesn't work (instead linking to its own page). If `asp-route-SomeId` is present in the link (with a valid GUID - not empty), the link works - with and without `asp-route-Step`.

Also, calling the link with only the two slugs works fine.

If I remove the `/{step:int}` from the @page it also works, but then the URL will end with `?Step=3` and I'd like to avoid that.

Is this some kind of limitation I don't see, or am I doing something wrong?

My goal is to be able to link to the page with and without `someId` in the URL and without ? in the URL.

Comment: I recommend avoiding the `asp-` tag-helpers entirely and instead create your own strongly-typed `IUrlHelper` extensions you can use with raw HTML attributes directly.

Comment: Until now I've been happy with the @page approach, but I'll read up on the IUrlHelper. Thanks :-)

Comment: The main reason I recommend it is because there's no compile-time checks or safety with `asp-page`, `asp-route`, `asp-controller` (and so on), whereas with custom `IUrlHelper` extensions you can use `nameof()` for Controllers and Actions to get compile-time guarantees that the `IUrlHelper.Action` method parameters are correct, for example.

Comment: I can indeed see the benefits of that. :) The @page method is just so straightforward and have not caused me any trouble until now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put `{someId:Guid?}` after `{step:int}`:

```
@page "{slug1}/{slug2}/{step:int}/{someId:Guid?}"
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! :-)